# how to highlight text as it is narrated in iphone

Tags: ios, text, highlight

I'm  new to Objective C and developing an app which requires I need to highlight the text when it is narrated i.e. 
for example consider the below sentence

```
"A Blue Jackal is dancing in the forest".
```

when `A` is narrated it should turn to red and all other words should be black and when `Blue` is narrated it should be turned to red and all other words will be shown in black.

I have used `UILabel` for the sentence and my problem is how to find the values of sound position and highlight it accordingly.

Could any one please share code snippet or  help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have used to narrate?

Comment: I have used audio file to narrate and it is played in the application using avaudioplayer

Comment: You can use Text to speech in ios 7 it saves your time

Comment: audio files are given. So I need to use it.  Do you know any utilities or tools which can give me the sound position values for words.

Comment: This will take a lot of hard work from your side. You will have to figure out a way to 'subtitle' these audio files yourself. Do you have the text ready? Or do you need to get that as well?

Comment: I solved my problem. After so much search I found a tool by name audacity with which we can find audio intervals and I used NSMutableAttributedString to store my text and changed the color of the words correspondingly using NSTimer and audio intervals. Thanks to all

Comment: @Harish : Can you post some code, because i am facing the same problem.